# pthread_create fails with EAGAIN - but only on a certain function

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have a number of classes that register with a notification class in my program. On a particular incoming event, the notifier calls an `update()` function in each class. In two of these callee's I'm now trying to spawn a small helper thread which will wait a few seconds, then initialize some external hardware and return.

The helper threads are created with the `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED` attribute, so I can avoid joining them.

This works fine for one of the threads (spawned from class1), but `pthread_create()` fails with `EAGAIN` in the other (from class2). According to the `pthread_create()` documentation, this happens if the application is out of resources. However, if I provide another incoming event, thread 1 can once again create its helper thread - while thread 2 still fails with the same error - and I can keep doing this with the same result.

The code I'm using is the same in both classes:

```
class class1_2 {
  public:
    void update();
  private:
    static void *init(void *self);
    pthread_t initThread;
    pthread_attr_t initThreadAttr;
}

void class1_2::update()
{
  printf("Class%d update()\n", classNumber);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&initThreadAttr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
  int retval = pthread_create(&initThread, &initThreadAttr, init, this);
  printf("Class%d thread created = %d\n", classNumber, retval);
}

void *class1_2::init(void *self)
{
  printf("Class%d init()\n", self->classNumber);
  //wait 3 seconds, then do stuff (~1 additional second)
  return;
}
```

In gdb I get the following output:

```
<incoming event>

Class1 update()
[New thread 1]
Class1 thread created=0

Class2 update()
Class2 thread created=11 (EAGAIN)

Class1 init()
[Thread 1 exited]

<incoming event>

Class1 update()
[New thread 2]
Class1 thread created=0

Class2 update()
Class2 thread created=11 (EAGAIN)

Class1 init()
[Thread 2 exited]

(...and so it goes on)
```

I've tried commenting out the thread creation in class1 (which works) - but class2 still fails, prompting me to think there is a subtle difference between the classes. The shown code is the same in both classes though, so if anyone has a clue as to what other variables/functions/etc could have an influence, or what else could be going on, I'd be very happy to hear it.

Comment: A complete testcase that people could copy/paste into a single file and try for themselves would make it much easier to see what you see.

Comment: Thanks for reading through it all - I was thinking about creating such a testcase, but as class1 and 2 in my application both have a good number of additional members and base classes, I thought I'd just start out with this, and hoped someone would point out an obvious error. As I got it solved myself, I'll just leave it at what it is though.

Comment: Are you ever calling `pthread_attr_init` to initialize the attribute object, before you call `pthread_attr_setdetachstate`?

Comment: Hah - can't test it right now, but I bet that's it... Yay for obvious errors and uninitialized variables that work sporadically and reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rep-whore purposes I'll promote my comment to an answer in case it's right ;)

Ensure you are calling `pthread_attr_init` to initialize the attribute object before you call `pthread_attr_setdetachstate`, and don't forget to destroy the attribute again too:

```
 void class1_2::update()
{
  printf("Class%d update()\n", classNumber);
  pthread_attr_init(&initThreadAttr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&initThreadAttr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
  int retval = pthread_create(&initThread, &initThreadAttr, init, this);
  printf("Class%d thread created = %d\n", classNumber, retval);
  pthread_attr_destroy(&initThreadAttr);
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it - although I've moved the handling of the attr to the constructor/destructor, as there's no reason to do it more than once for each class...

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of tinkering I got it working. Instead of creating the threads in a detached state, I'm detaching them after creation with `pthread_detach()`.

So, my `update()` has been changed to:

```
void class1_2::update()
{
  printf("Class%d update()\n", classNumber);
  int retval = pthread_create(&initThread, &initThreadAttr, init, this);
  printf("Class%d thread created = %d\n", classNumber, retval);
  retval = pthread_detach(initThread);
  printf("Class%d thread detached = %d\n", classNumber, retval);
}
```

If anyone has experienced something similar, or can otherwise shed some light on this, I'm still interested though.